# iPod Nano Running Playlist - Does it always have to start from the first song?

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano, health.app

I have the latest iPod Nano and I use it when I run. I have created several playlists for that purpose and sync'ed them to my Nano. Some of the playlists are 70-90 minutes long.

However, the Nano won't let me start a playlist from a song different than the 1st song or let me shuffle songs within a playlist.

So, for example, I want to run on a specific music album which is 70 minutes long and I always have to listed to the songs from the first 45 minutes of the album (because I run for 45 minute sessions).

Is there a way around this?

Regards,